# gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert for multiple files

Tags: google-drive-api

```
  var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
    fileId: fileId,
    resource: {
        value:"user@gmail.com",
        type:"user",
        role:"reader"
    }
  });
```

This code sent one email to "user@gmail.com" that shares one file: how can I do the same with multiple fileId in one time / one email?

Can't find the answer here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert#request

Answer (score 0):

It seems you'll be needing to perform [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#manipulating_permissions_with_batch_requests) for multiple permissions. Drive docs states:

> We strongly recommend using batch requests to modify multiple
>   permissions.

Here's a snippet for batch requests in Java:

```
String fileId = "1sTWaJ_j7PkjzaBWtNc3IzovK5hQf21FbOw9yLeeLPNQ";
JsonBatchCallback<Permission> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Permission>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e,
                          HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
            throws IOException {
        // Handle error
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Permission permission,
                          HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Permission ID: " + permission.getId());
    }
};
BatchRequest batch = driveService.batch();
Permission userPermission = new Permission()
        .setType("user")
        .setRole("writer")
        .setEmailAddress("example@appsrocks.com");
driveService.permissions().create(fileId, userPermission)
        .setFields("id")
        .queue(batch, callback);

Permission domainPermission = new Permission()
        .setType("domain")
        .setRole("reader")
        .setDomain("appsrocks.com");
driveService.permissions().create(fileId, domainPermission)
        .setFields("id")
        .queue(batch, callback);

batch.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using the v2 https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions and your code seems to be referred to the v3 https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create could you help?

Comment: I've found this doc reference but there isn't the javascript example https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-sharing#examples (I'm using javascript). Thanks

Comment: Here's the link to using [batch requests in v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/batch#overview).